# C++: Monitoring multiple value types

Tags: c++, debugging, boost, polymorphism, type-safety

I want to write a class that can monitor a bunch of different values for easy debugging.  Imagine setting "watches" in a visual debugger.  I'm picturing something like this:

```
struct Foo {
    int x = 0;
    std::string s = "bar";
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    ValueMonitor::watch("number", &f.x);
    ValueMonitor::watch("string", &f.s);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        ++f.x;
        if (i > 5) {
            f.s = "new string";
        }

        // print the current value of the variable with the given key
        // these should change as the loop goes on
        ValueMonitor::print("number");
        ValueMonitor::print("string");
        // or
        ValueMonitor::printAll();

        // obviously this would be unnecessary in this example since I
        // have easy access to f, but imagine monitoring different
        // values from all over a much larger code base
    }
}
```

Then these could be easily monitored somewhere in the application's GUI or whatever.

However, I don't know how to handle the different types that would be stored in this class.  Ideally, I should be able to store anything that has a string representation.  I have a few ideas but none of them really seem right:

1. Store pointers to a superclass that defines a toString function or operator<<, like Java's `Object`.  But this would require me to make wrappers for any primitives I want to monitor.
2. Something like `boost::any` or `boost::spirit::hold_any`.  I think `any` needs to be type casted before I can print it...  I guess I could try/catch casting to a bunch of different types, but that would be slow.  `hold_any` requires defined stream operators, which would be perfect... but I can't get it to work with pointers.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In your example I do not see the benefit of using a `ValueMonitor`. In place of `ValueMonitor::print("number");` you could as well have `std::cout << f.x << std::endl;` with exactly the same effect but much less code

Comment: Alternatively you could use a debugger

Comment: Yeah, my example could be better.  But the advantage would be that I could print out those values from anywhere in my application without having to pass around the objects in question, regardless of the complexity of the application.  Imagine dozens of different classes like Foo nested in different ways, which would typically be more complicated to print than just `f.x`.

Comment: Cheat like hell. Serialize everything to string and store the string. Only one datatype to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution somewhere else.  I was pretty blown away, so might as well post it here for future reference.  It looks something like this:

```
class Stringable
{
public:
    virtual ~Stringable() {};
    virtual std::string str() const = 0;

    using Ptr = std::shared_ptr<Stringable>;
};

template <typename T>
class StringableRef : public Stringable
{
private:
    T* _ptr;

public:
    StringableRef(T& ref)
        : _ptr(&ref) {}
    virtual ~StringableRef() {}

    virtual std::string str() const
    {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << *_ptr;
        return ss.str();
    }
};

class ValueMonitor
{
private:
    static std::map<std::string, Stringable::Ptr> _values;

public:
    ValueMonitor() {}
    ~ValueMonitor() {}

    template <typename T>
    static void watch(const std::string& label, T& ref)
    {
        _values[label] = std::make_shared<StringableRef<T>>(ref);
    }

    static void printAll()
    {
        for (const auto& valueItr : _values)
        {
            const String& name = valueItr.first;
            const std::shared_ptr<Stringable>& value = valueItr.second;
            std::cout << name << ": " << value->str() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    static void clear()
    {
        _values.clear();
    }
};

std::map<std::string, Stringable::Ptr> ValueMonitor::_values;
```

.

```
int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    std::string s = "test"
    ValueMonitor::watch("number", i);
    ValueMonitor::watch("string", s);
    ValueMonitor::printAll();

    i = 10;
    s = "new string";
    ValueMonitor::printAll();

    return 0;
}
```